# Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation matrices mult

Tags: c, valgrind

I've got this function for matrices multiplication, standard triple for-loop.
Input are pointers to two structs (shown below the function). Name of the function is at line 125 (line 126 is { ). It outputs correct numbers, tested on multiple inputs. However valgrind doesn't like it.

```
void matrix_mult(matrix_t* matrix_1, matrix_t* matrix_2)
{
    int** mult;
    mult = calloc(matrix_1 -> height, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i; i < (matrix_1 -> height); ++i)
    {
        mult[i] = calloc(matrix_2 -> width, sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < (matrix_2 -> width); ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < (matrix_1 -> width); ++k)
            {
                mult[i][j] += (matrix_1 -> array[i][k]) * (matrix_2 -> array[k][j]);
            }
        }
        free(matrix_1 -> array[i]);
    }
    free(matrix_1 -> array);
    matrix_1 -> array = mult;
    matrix_1 -> width = matrix_2 -> width;
}
```

And matrix_t is this struct:

```
struct matrix
{
    int height;
    int width;
    int** array;
};
```

valgrind output is:

```
==837== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==837==    at 0x400ED5: matrix_mult (main.c:129)
==837==    by 0x400F84: main (main.c:153)
==837==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==837==    at 0x400D6C: matrix_mult (main.c:126)
```

same for:

```
matrix_mult (main.c:131)
matrix_mult (main.c:131)
matrix_mult (main.c:136)
matrix_mult (main.c:139)
```

Comment: `for (int i; i < (matrix_1 -> height); ++i) ...` What is the initial value of `i`? Uninitialized local variables will haven an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value.

Comment: i'm such an i***t, looking for that mistake for like 20 minutes. You are right, it was that...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in the code snippet above.

- `for (int i; i < (matrix_1 -> height); ++i)`
  Here `i` is uninitialised, thats a concern as `i` will contain a random (garbage) value. With that, the loop may or not be entered.
- You seem to assume that the calls to `calloc` would succeed. There is a need of error checking. Check if `calloc` returned NULL, if it does, handle the error.
- Redundant code.

  ```
  mult = calloc(matrix_1 -> height, sizeof(int*));
  for (int i; i < (matrix_1 -> height); ++i)`  
  {  
      mult[i] = calloc(matrix_2 -> width, sizeof(int));
      // some code
  }
  ```

Once you fix the issue with uninitiated `i` the first call to `calloc` (before the loop is entered) is wasted, unless the data in struct is such that the function `matrix_mult` is intended to be called but loop is not being entered, which would be weird (?!).